# Bounding box of al list of circles

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a list of circles with a location and radius for each circle e.g., `[(x, y, r), ...]` .

I need to find a bounding box for the entire list so that all circles are contained in the box. 
I tried going over all circles and finding the minimum and maximum `x` and `y` values but this does not take into account the **radius** of each circle.

```py
xlist = []
ylist = []
for circle in circle_list:
    xlist.append(circle[0])
    ylist.append(circle[1])

# top-left and bottom-right corners
bbox = [(min(xlist), min(ylist)), (max(xlist), max(ylist))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take radius into account while creating `xlist` and `ylist`. It is like:

```py
xlist = []
ylist = []
for circle in circle_list:
    x,y,r = circle[0], circle[1], circle[2]
    xlist.append(x-r)
    xlist.append(x+r)
    ylist.append(y-r)
    ylist.append(y+r)
```